# Помогите подобрать эпитеты к указанным внутри словам.

Tags: род-существительного

Помогите подобрать эпитеты к следующим словам:

Полынь, прорубь, моль,  спесь, медь, блажь, гавань, картечь, сень, колыбель, свирель, рысь, ель, гортань, лань, шаль (цыганская; есть еще цветастая, но это звучит отчужденно), сирень (белая, других не подобрал),  доблесть (воинская; есть еще хорошие эпитеты, как этот??), знать (родовитая; но этот тоже звучит незнакомо для моих ушей),  мелочь, новь, суть, фальшь, фасоль, трость, лень, грань, степь.

Знаю, список вышел длинным, за что, я очень извиняюсь, но я был бы весьма Вам благодарен, если бы Вы смогли помочь мне с этим. А это мне нужно, чтобы быстро вспомнить род вышеуказанных существительных. Благодарю!

Comment: Чтобы быстро вспомнить род? У всех - женский. И вы уверены, что вам нужны именно эпитеты, а не просто определения? Например, в вашем словосочетании "белая сирень" слово "белая" - определение, но не эпитет.

Comment: А в чем разница между эпитетом и определением? Я думал это одно и то же. Конечно, можно и определения) Я знаю, что у всех женский. Но посредством других определителей трудно найти род, к примеру, эта медь или этот медь ничего не поясняет для меня. Почему-то, я даже был уверен, что фальшь это сущ-ое в муж. роде) Поэтому я хотел посредством определителей запомнить род таких сущ-ых (местная печать, невосполнимая брешь, дорожная пыль тд.)

Comment: Читать  надо  больше.

Comment: Да ладно, не наезжайте на человека. К некоторым словам я, пока хоть что-то придумала, мозг сломала!

Comment: @roger, не обижайтесь, пожалуйста, можно нескромный вопрос?  
У Вас русский - родной? От этого зависит, как лучше Вам объяснить тут или иную ситуацию или правило.  

Вообще существительных мужского рода на -ь очень немного (помимо тех, что с суффиксом на "-тель"), они в большинстве своём на слуху. 
У носителя русского как родного проблем с определением рода обычно не возникает, а в словарях для иностранцев фигурирует от силы полусотня таких слов.  
Вообще я бы рекомендовал запомнить как раз несколько слов именно мужского рода: яичный шампунь, черный ферзь, белый лебедь, душистый имбирь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Горькая полынь, глубокая прорубь, вредная моль, неуемная спесь, окислившаяся медь, очередная блажь, тихая гавань, ружейная (?) картечь, благодатная сень, резная колыбель, пастушья свирель, ловкая рысь, раскидистая ель, человеческая гортань, трепетная (кто бы сомневался))) лань, кружевная шаль, душистая (махровая) сирень, трудовая доблесть, высшая знать, латунная мелочь (если речь о деньгах, но больше ничего не придумывается), трудовая новь (есть такая газета), истинная суть, музыкальная фальшь, красная (белая, мелкая) фасоль, бамбуковая (резная) трость, невероятная лень (это обо мне!))), последняя грань, бескрайняя (полынная, ковыльная) степь.
Надеюсь, хоть чем-то Вам помогла.

Comment: Млинн, большущее спасибо!!))))) Конечно) Более чем помогли :))

Comment: Не, прав *bernard*, это надо ж такое придумать! Знать все невозможно, но основы своего языка все же надо, а для этого - читать, читать... Чтение - вот лучшее учение!